# WTP api reference

Tags: eclipse, api, documentation, reference, eclipse-wtp

Can anyone point me to the documentation and api reference for Eclipse WTP. I simply cannot seem to find it either on google or in the eclipse documentation.

**Update:**

I am looking for the api reference for the various components like WST, JST, Server Api, etc. But I cant find their javadoc in the eclipse help file where it is usually present. Can you point me to those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a consolidated developer guide and API reference. There are various articles covering a variety of topics and then there is javadoc (mostly accessed by installing WTP source bundles). I recommend installing the WTP SDK features. This will give you the source bundles. That should also add some developer guide content under help too.

Once you have access to source/javadoc, you will want to search for references to docs on specific topics or ask here. Things like adding facet, adding new server type, etc. If you describe what you are trying to do, someone may be able to point you at an article or a wiki.

You can use the following repository to install WTP SDK:

http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/helios/

Comment: I am looking for the api reference for the various components like WST, JST, Server Api, etc. But I cant find their javadoc in the eclipse help file where it is usually present. Can you point me to those?

Comment: hmm. i have the 'ide for j2ee dev' pack.

Comment: is the wtp sdk a separate download. what is the update site for it?

Comment: The WTP sdk features are not present in "ide for java ee devlopers" package, which is meant for end users. Your Eclipse install will already know about the main plugins repository, which does contain WTP SDK... http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/

Comment: I cannot see any WTP SDK in the update site for the main repository as you can see in the screenshot http://screencast.com/t/AG5Zvwrp. Can you point me to a repo that does contain the sdk?

Comment: Try this one: http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/helios/

Comment: works! can you update your answer with this, so that i can mark it 'answered'